# List AD Users in List Box in Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface, active-directory, listbox

I'm currently making my own administration tool and one function should end up being "Disable Account" (Active Directory User).

The Code I currently have is the following:

```
#Assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#Frame
$frmDisableUser                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmDisableUser.ClientSize       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(378,99)
$frmDisableUser.text             = "Disable User"
$frmDisableUser.TopMost          = $false
$frmDisableUser.BackColor        = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#ffffff")
$frmDisableUser.TopMost            = $false
$frmDisableUser.FormBorderStyle    = "FixedSingle"
$frmDisableUser.startposition      = "CenterScreen"
$frmDisableUser.MaximizeBox        = $false

#AD Users Listbox
$lstADUsers                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$lstADUsers.width                = 356
$lstADUsers.height               = 20
$lstADUsers.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(9,18)
$lstADUsers.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

#Disable Account Button
$btnDisableAccount               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnDisableAccount.text          = "Disable"
$btnDisableAccount.width         = 100
$btnDisableAccount.height        = 30
$btnDisableAccount.location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(265,53)
$btnDisableAccount.Font          = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$btnDisableAccount.Add_Click({

})

#Adds all elements into th eframe
$frmDisableUser.controls.AddRange(@($lstADUsers,$btnDisableAccount))

#Shows the frame
$frmDisableUser.ShowDialog()
```

The Command I use to get all AD Users as an output is the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "true")} | Select-Object Name
```

I think the easiest way is to make it using arrays but I'm not really familiar with arrays to be honest... I'd be very happy if you could help me!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add items to the listbox with

$lstADUsers.Items.Add()

I've updated your code to demonstrate this.

```
#Assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#Frame
$frmDisableUser                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmDisableUser.ClientSize       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(388,299)
$frmDisableUser.text             = "Disable User"
$frmDisableUser.TopMost          = $false
$frmDisableUser.BackColor        = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#ffffff")
$frmDisableUser.TopMost            = $false
$frmDisableUser.FormBorderStyle    = "FixedSingle"
$frmDisableUser.startposition      = "CenterScreen"
$frmDisableUser.MaximizeBox        = $false

#AD Users Listbox
$lstADUsers                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$lstADUsers.width                = 356
$lstADUsers.height               = 220
$lstADUsers.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(9,18)
$lstADUsers.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$lstADUsers.AutoSize = $false
Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "true")} | foreach{[void]$lstADUsers.Items.Add($_.name)}


#Disable Account Button
$btnDisableAccount               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnDisableAccount.text          = "Disable"
$btnDisableAccount.width         = 100
$btnDisableAccount.height        = 30
$btnDisableAccount.location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(265,249)
$btnDisableAccount.Font          = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$btnDisableAccount.Add_Click({

})

#Adds all elements into th eframe
$frmDisableUser.controls.AddRange(@($lstADUsers,$btnDisableAccount))

#Shows the frame
$frmDisableUser.ShowDialog()
```

Note the cast to [void] - this is to suppress the output from the .Add() method. It emits the the index number for that item in the array.

I also suggest you check out https://poshgui.com/ if you haven't already. It can help you not only design forms but also learn how to interact with the GUI components.

Comment: That helped a lot, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Items` property of a ListBox (which is an ObjectCollection object) has a method called `AddRange` with which you can enter an array.
Just get a string array of usernames and enter it in one go.
To make the list better readable, sort it alphabetically. You could also set the 'Sorted' property of the Listbox to $true, but sorting before adding to the listbox is more efficient.

```
$users = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'").Name | Sort-Object
```

Next add the array to the listbox

```
$lstADUsers.Items.AddRange($users)
```

P.S. If you need to refresh the listbox data with the result of a new call to Get-ADUser, clear the listbox items first with `$lstADUsers.Items.Clear()`